# Return string after specific character

Tags: tcl

I have a question regarding possibility of getting string after specific character in TCL.

Whan I mean is :

Input:

```
abcdefgh = hgfedcba
```

Output:

```
hgfedcba
```

(return everything after "=" without possible whitespaces)

This is what I was using:

```
regexp {abcdefgh=\s+"(.*)"} $text_var all variable
```

In some cases it is ok (with spaces) but when there is no whitespaces then it is not working.

Comment: What have you tried?  Have you googled and found any results that might help you?  I quickly googled for "tcl string split" and "tcl string trim" -- the results may be a starting point.  So might regular expressions.

Comment: Also, a link to the Tcl man pages: https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/contents.htm -- look up `split`, `string`, `regexp` and maybe `re_syntax` if for Tcl's regex syntax

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
% regexp {abcdefgh\s*=\s*(\S+)} "abcdefgh = hgfedcba" all variable
1
% set variable
hgfedcba
% regexp {abcdefgh\s*=\s*(\S+)} "abcdefgh=hgfedcba" all variable
1
% set variable
hgfedcba
%
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming

```
% set s {abcdefgh = hgfedcba}
# => abcdefgh = hgfedcba
```

(or the same thing without one or both of the blanks) you could do one of these:

```
% scan $s {%*[^=]= %s}
# => hgfedcba
```

(Scan the string for a substring not containing "=", then advance past the equals sign and optional whitespace, then return the rest of the string.)

```
string trim [lindex [split $s =] 1]
```

(Split the string at the equals sign, return the (whitespace-trimmed) second resulting element.)

```
string trim [string range $s [string first = $s]+1 end]
```

(Return the (whitespace-trimmed) substring starting after the equals sign.)

```
string trim [lindex [regexp -inline {[^=]+$} $s] 0]
```

(Return the (whitespace-trimmed) first match of one or more characters, not including the equals sign, anchored on the end of the string.)

```
lindex [regexp -inline -all {[a-h]+} $s] 1
```

(Return the second match of consecutive characters from the set "a" to "h".)

```
string trimleft [string trimleft $s {abcdefgh }] {= }
```

(Remove all characters from the start of the string that occur in the set "a" to "h" and blank, then remove from start of the resulting string any characters that are equals sign or blank.)